# What's the name of the concept I need to learn to solve this: field used before Firebase data updates it

Tags: java, android, firebase

So I have a list that is updated from firebase.

In my mainactivity's onCreate, I set the listener for changes. However, the next line of code uses the list immediately. This line runs before my list is updated, thus causing an error.

What is the name of the concept i need to grasp in order to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe async callback?

Comment: Hi Philip, I already use onDataChange to update my list, but my list is used before onDataChange updates the list. Am I misunderstanding async callback?


edited, accidentally pressed enter.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database callbacks are **asynchronous**.  You'll need to learn asynchronous programming to deal with most of the Firebase SDKs.  It means that method calls return immediately and expect to receive results some time later in a callback that was passed as an argument to the method.  See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) for more information.

Comment: Could you please explain why you use asynchronous programming instead of multithreading to wait until the field has been updated? 

ps: thank you Doug!

Comment: That's just the way the APIs are designed - they handle all the threading internally  There's no blocking version of the API that would require you to do your own threading.  This is often safer and easier for most developers to use.

Comment: OK, after reading the docs, I still can't quite figure out how I can fix this issue... could you point me in the right direction?